# different contents of multi column and switching between columns

Tags: environments, multicolumn

Is there any package I can use to have different contents for multicolumn and switch freely between them? For example, something like,

```
\begin{column1}
    column 1 text ...
\end{column1}

\begin{column2}
    column 2 text ... (more than a page)
\end{column2}

\begin{column1}
    column 1 text conti...
\end{column1}

\begin{column2}
    column 2 text conti...
\end{column2}

\begin{column1}
    column 1 text contii...
\end{column1}
```

which output

```
-(page 1)-
column 1 text           | column 2 text
column 1 text conti...  | ...
column 1 text contii... | ...
-(page 2)-
                        | ...
                        | column 2 text conti...
```

Comment: see if a  `longtable` with tree column fulfill your demands.